# How to get a Tab's name in a GWT TabPanel

Tags: gwt

I have a tab panel where I add tabs dynamically.

At a given point it can look like:

```
tabPanel.add(new HTML("Dashboard"), new Hyperlink("Dashboard", "dashboard"));       
tabPanel.add(new CashGameTabPage(this), new Hyperlink("Cash Games", "cash"));
tabPanel.add(new TournamentTabPage(this), new Hyperlink("Tournament", "tournament"));
```

I would like to check if a Tab already exists. If it exists, I should get its index. If it does not exist I should get 0. I was thinking as a function such as:

```
public static int getIndexIfAlreadyExists(DecoratedTabPanel tabPanel, String title) {
    int tabcount = tabPanel.getTabBar().getTabCount();      
    for(int i = 0; i < tabcount;i++) {              
       if(/*TODO get a Tab Text */.equals(title))
          return i;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to get

```
getIndexIfAlreadyExists(tabPanel, "Dashboard") -> 0
getIndexIfAlreadyExists(tabPanel, "Cash Games") -> 1
getIndexIfAlreadyExists(tabPanel, "Tournament") -> 2
```

However I do not manage to find a method to retrieve the Text. Any idea how to achieve this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the Widgets you added to the tab panel, you can pass them (instead of the the titles) for easy check via iterating through the Widgets in the tab panel and comparing with the one you have at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabPanel doesn't really make this easy. It may be possible to get the Hyperlink widget somehow via `TabPanel.getTabBar().getTab(index)`, but I'm not sure.

This is approximately what I would do:

```
public class TabPanelModel {

    private final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final TabPanel tabPanel;

    public TabPanelModel(final TabPanel tabPanel) {
        this.tabPanel = tabPanel;
    }

    public void addToPanel(Widget widget, final String linktext, final String targetHistoryToken) {
        tabPanel.add(widget, new Hyperlink(linktext, targetHistoryToken));
        titleList.add(linktext);
    }

    /* similar for remove, ... */

    public int getIndexIfAlreadyExists(final String linktext) {
        return titleList.indexOf(linktext) + 1;
    }

}
```

The approach uses a small amount of additional memory, but I believe that it's better to have such information in a clean model anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for TabBar.getTabHTML(int index).

However, I typically do something like Chris suggested, but create a data object for the tabs themselves

```
public interface Tab {
  String getName(); // or Widget
  Widget getContent();
}
```

and add tabs via a wrapper on TabPanel:

```
List<Tab> tabs;

public void addTab(Tab tab) {
  tabs.add(tab);
  tabPanel.add(tab.getContent(), tab.getName);
}

public Tab getTab(int i) {...}
```

Also, if you don't use the new LayoutPanel classes, you should give them a look.